# read each part of a token response in android

Tags: android, token

Hi i need to read the token number of a token response the token that i received have this body, `{"1":"2","2":{"3":"numbertoken"}}`, i can read the 2 and the 3 response but the numbertoken is a instance of 3 how can i have this numbertoken, thanks!

```
e01-25 11:33:09.446 7351-7351/ W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for token
01-25 11:33:09.446 7351-7351/ W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
01-25 11:33:09.446 7351-7351/ W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:514)
```

Comment: Where is your code showing how you tried to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `JSONObject.get("2")`,you get a JSONObject again,it have a pair which key is 3 and value is numbertoken,so you just need try to get the  numbertoken again:`JSONObject.get("2").get("3")`

Comment: thanks FireSun, and sorry for the question, i did my best trying to explain myself, i solve my problem with your advice.